# Set partition Array in Ruby

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am working on a script to reload a server with a custom partition scheme. I have this working in Python but I cannot get the same code working in Ruby as I am new to the language.

```
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'pp'

client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:timeout => 120)
server_id = REDACTED

config = { 

    'upgradeHardDriveFirmware' => 0,
        'upgradeBios' => 0,
        'hardDrives' => [
            {
                'complexType' => "SoftLayer_Hardware_Component_HardDrive",
                'partitions' => [
                    { 'name' => { "/" => { "minimumSize" => "212"} } },
                    { 'name' => { "/boot" => { "minimumSize" => ".25" } } },
                    { 'name' => { "/swap0" => { "minimumSize" => "32"} } },
                    { 'name' => { "/tmp" => { "minimumSize" => "212"} } },
                    { 'name' => { "/var" => { "minimumSize" => "212"} } },
                    { 'name' => { "/remove" => { "minimumSize" => "1", "grow" => "1" } } } 
                ]
            }
        ]
     }

setclient = client['Hardware_Server']
reload = setclient.object_with_id(server_id).reloadOperatingSystem('FORCE', config)

pp reload
```

When I run the script I get an error about the partition array beginning with /:

```
$ ruby osReloadCustomPartitions.rb
    /Users/ryan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/xmlrpc/client.rb:272:in `call': 
Partition (Array) must begin with a / (XMLRPC::FaultException)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below config:

```
config = { 
    'upgradeHardDriveFirmware' => 0,
        'upgradeBios' => 0,
        'hardDrives' => [
            {
                'complexType' => "SoftLayer_Hardware_Component_HardDrive",
                'partitions' => [
                    { 'name' =>  "/",  "minimumSize" => "212"  },
                    { 'name' =>  "/boot",  "minimumSize" => ".25" },
                    { 'name' =>  "/swap0", "minimumSize" => "32" },
                    { 'name' => "/tmp" ,  "minimumSize" => "212"},
                    { 'name' =>  "/var",  "minimumSize" => "212" },
                    { 'name' =>  "/remove",  "minimumSize" => "1", "grow" => "1"  } 
                ]
            }
        ]
     }
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. Now to read up on how arrays work in Ruby.